# Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'?

Tags: haskell, ambiguous-type-variable

While learning Haskell I'm trying to write a function that given a number will give its successor in a [Collatz sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture):

```
next :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a
next x
    | odd x = x * 3 + 1
    | otherwise = x / 2
```

When I run `next 7` I get:

```
<interactive>:150:1: error:
* Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
  prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Show Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
    instance Show Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
    instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
    ...plus 22 others
    ...plus 12 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Two questions:

1. Am I using the best class constraints in my signature?
2. Assuming I am, how can I `show` the result of `next 7` ?

Comment: No types satisfy `(Fractional a, Integral a)`. You want to drop the `Fractional` and use `\`div\`` instead of ```/```

Comment: Thank you - that works and I've learned something new. Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I suggest using a more specific type: `Int -> Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Collatz sequence is an integer sequence, so it wouldn't be necessary making the result Fractional.

```
next :: (Integral a) => a -> a
```

To be able to get an integer from a division, you should use `div` function. Note that division will always be exact as you are going to divide only even numbers:

```
next x
    | odd x = x * 3 + 1
    | otherwise = x `div` 2
```